# How do I access the Bitshares that I received from my Protoshares "snapshot"

Tags: bitshares

I have had some Protoshares for a while.  At some point (according to my fuzzy memory) there was a "snapshot" which gave me the right to Bitshares.

I still have access to my Protoshares wallet but haven't installed a Bitshares wallet.  How do I access the Bitshares that I received from the "snapshot"?

Answer (score 4):

Install the BitShares wallet. Create an account and go to that account page. Select the "Keys" tab and import the wallet.dat file.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the private keys for the addresse(s) you donated from. You can get them from the client you used and need to import them into an account in your client.

1. Open up you client
2. Let it sync with the network
3. Create a new local account (no need to register it)
4. Got to the settings of your account
5. Go to the "keys" tab
6. Import the private keys
7. Get the `wallet.dat` file from the bitcoin-core/protoshares client and import as "Bitcoin wallet"
8. Click `Import`

You should see your funds instantly. Also note that you certainly also have a *vested* balance from **the merger** with DNS and VOTE. You can check the balance with `wallet_check_sharedrop` and claim your vested balance using `wallet_collect_vested_balances accountname`. Note, that the vested balance can be collected over a 2 year period, no matter the exact date of collection (except for the transaction fee).